# How do I make the Glulx window larger?

Tags: glulxe, photopia

I downloaded Windows Glulxe from [here](http://www.davidkinder.co.uk/glulxe.html), and tried to use it to play [Photopia 2.01](http://adamcadre.ac/if.html). But the window is very small and contains only little text:

[image]

Is there a way to make the window larger?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself: instead of using Glulxe, it is better to use [Gargoyle](https://github.com/garglk/garglk/releases), which is newer (latest version from 2019) and can open the same Glulx files. With Gargoyle, it is possible to resize the window to any desired size.